# How to patch a property with mocker in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I have a project that I need to mock a property using the `mocker` fixture. Its using pytest and pytest-mock:

```
pip install pytest pytest-mock
```

A simple example of the problem:

I have the `foo` class in the *foo.py* file:

```
class Foo:
    @property
    def bar(self):
        return "x"
```

And I have to test it mocking the property `bar`:

```py
import foo

def test_foo(mocker):
    mocker.patch("foo.Foo.bar", return_value="y")
    f = foo.Foo()
    assert f.bar == "y"
```

But when I patch it, the bar behaves like a callable and not like an attribute, how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using [PropertyMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) yet?

Comment: Just used and worked, if you post the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to so using the `mocker.PropertyMock` just like @idjaw comment.

```
import foo


def test_foo(mocker):
    mocker.patch('foo.Foo.bar', return_value="y", new_callable=mocker.PropertyMock)
    f = foo.Foo()
    assert f.bar == "y"
```

This made the test work.